# English possessive case, when 2 s are near

Tags: british-english

James's car is white, or Dickens's books are popular. can we put 2 s together and if so how do you pronounce it naturally and nicely?

Answer (score 1):

`James's car is white` is correct usage.  It is saying the car that James owns is white.  When you show possession to a singular entity, you add `'s` to that entity.  This also means that `Dickens's books are popular` is correct usage as well.

The link posted by choster above has some great explanations and examples.